# Mount VHD at Boot in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: boot, windows-server-2008, vhd

I need a way to attach a VHD at boot in Windows Server 2008 R2.   I tried to accomplish this task by creating a diskpart script that attached the vdisk at boot, which would work if it were not for the fact that it triggers UAC when I call on diskpart to mount the image.   What is the point of auto mounting a VHD at boot if I have to click Yes to accept the UAC?  Is there some other way of mounting VHD images at boot in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

So, just to let everyone know I found a free software solution that allows mouting VHDs automatically at boot.  The tool is called Gizmo Manager.   Check it out @ http://arainia.com/software/gizmo/

Answer (score 0):

Try [VHD Attach](http://www.jmedved.com/vhdattach/):

> If so desired you can also use this program to **attach various virtual disks upon system start-up.** It is your choice whether this will be done in full-access or read-only mode.